# Correctly enque child styles and javascript

Tags: php, wordpress

I am  using wordpress 4.9.5 and I am en-queuing in my `functions.php` my styles as the following:

```
function enqueue_parent_theme_style()
{
    if ( is_page( 'product builder' )  || is_page('shopping products')) {

        $parentStyle = 'parent-style';

        //css
        wp_enqueue_style($parentStyle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-4.0.0', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array($parentStyle));
        wp_enqueue_style('dataTables', '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css', array($parentStyle) );
        wp_enqueue_style('dataTables-1.10.16', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css', array($parentStyle));

        //js
        wp_enqueue_script('font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js', NULL, '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('main-shopping-product-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);

        wp_localize_script('main-shopping-product-js', 'shoppingproductData', array(
            'root_url' => get_site_url(),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
        ));
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style');
```

As you can see I only want to load my child css/javascript on two child pages, `product builder` and `shopping products`. My css/javascript works on these two pages:

[image]

On my two child pages the theme's css and javascript is working perfectly fine. However, when I go back to my main theme pages, the css and javascript is broken.

The pages look like the following:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

My browser console shows the following:

[image]

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan My `css/javascript` are not displayed correctly. See my updated post for an example.

Comment: look at browser console. how many 404 errors are there?

Comment: You're loading your theme's main `style.css` _conditionally_ as well, which is why there's no styles / js on your home page.  Do you ONLY want theme styles on these product pages?

Comment: @cale_b I added `, array($parentStyle)`l ike the following `wp_enqueue_style($parentStyle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parentStyle));` to my `style.css`. Then did a hard reload in chrome. I still get the broken css/javascript on my main pages.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan My console does not show any 404 errors. Please see my post update.

Comment: ok, check in the page, if there loads bootstrap.css file( any version of it )

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan On my main theme page no bootstrap occurance can be found. Furthermore, if I comment out in my child theme the error I still get the above broken css/js. (even after a hard reload)

Comment: what do you mean `no bootstrap occurance`? can you move all `wp_enqueue_style` functions out of `if` statement. the page still shows broken?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I fixed it with your help! I moved out the `    $parentStyle = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style($parentStyle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');` of the if-block. So that this style is loaded no matter which page. And now it works!

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `style.css`, which was in the [`if` condition](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php):

```
if ( is_page( 'product builder' )  || is_page('shopping products')) {
    $parentStyle = 'parent-style';
    //css
    wp_enqueue_style($parentStyle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
```

The `style.css` file contains all css rules( menu part, too ), which construct the pages layouts. Moving out from condition that part will load `style.css` file in all pages:

```
function enqueue_parent_theme_style()
{
    $parentStyle = 'parent-style';
//css
    wp_enqueue_style($parentStyle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

    if (is_page('product builder') || is_page('shopping products')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-4.0.0', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array($parentStyle));
        wp_enqueue_style('dataTables', '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css', array($parentStyle));
        wp_enqueue_style('dataTables-1.10.16', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css', array($parentStyle));

//js
        wp_enqueue_script('font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js', NULL, '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('main-shopping-product-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);

        wp_localize_script('main-shopping-product-js', 'shoppingproductData', array(
            'root_url' => get_site_url(),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
        ));
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style');
```